# Construct object without reference?

Tags: c#, reference

Im almost certain this defies the basic laws of C#, but is it possible to construct an 'array' or 'collection' of items by reference?

Failing that, is there any other way to construct the checkboxes in a parametered static method?

Hopefully my psuedocode makes sense (everything concerning `Construct2`)

```
CheckBox cb = null, cb2 = null;

Main()
{
    Construct(ref cb);//works
    Construct2(new []{ref cb, ref cb2});//isnt going to work!
}

static void Construct(ref CheckBox cb){
    cb = new CheckBox();//works
}

static void Construct2(CheckBox[] cbs) { //
    cbs[0] = new CheckBox();
    cbs[1] = new CheckBox();
    //for (int i = 0; i < cbs.Length;i++){
    //    cbs[i] = new CheckBox();
    //}
}
```

Comment: In .NET, collections of objects are already collections of references to those objects.  Are you talking about having the collection contain references of references?

Comment: But why would you want to do that?

Comment: @MikeC Yep, I want to construct the items I pass in and have them keep their original reference.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's not to do with it being inside a loop - ive clarified my Construct2 method. See line 6 for the crux of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass an array of `ref` variables like that. If you want to be able to construct "into" multiple variables like that I think you'll need to pass in setters of some kind:

```
void Construct2 (params Action<Checkbox>[] cbas)
{
    foreach (var cba in cbas) cba(new Checkbox());
}

Construct2(
    (c) => cb = c,
    (c) => cb2 = c);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Failing that, is there any other way to construct the checkboxes in a parametered static method?

Yes, have the method *return* an array of checkboxes instead of trying to pass in a reference.

```
static CheckBox[] Construct2()
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible in C#.  In order to use pointers you have to declare your code within an `unsafe` context, and compile the application with `/unsafe`.  However, this would only work for a value type such as a struct and would not work for managed objects (which is `Checkbox` and most everything you would probably use).